# Как осуществить проверку на пустое значение dataProvider yii2

Tags: yii2

Как осуществить проверку  на пустое значение dataProvider. У меня когда нет показывает пустое значение, а мне бы хотелось редиректить в случае если выборка из БД будет пустой.

Comment: Посмотреть количество элементов, например. $provider->getCount();

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.